# How to access a group calendar using Microsoft Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to access a group calendar using the microsoft graph api as the application (I don't want to use delegate permissions).

If I request calendar events using the below I get the events for the user just fine.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[emailAddress]/events
```

If I make a request to the following I get group information:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[groupId]/
```

If I make a request to this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[groupId]/events
```

I get "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
In azure portal, I've given my app service the following Application permissions:

```
Calendars.Read
Calendars.Read.Shared
Group.Read.All
User.Read.All
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applications permissions to list events is currently not supported. Also, listing events using delegated permissions with a Personal accounts is not supported.  Please refer to  [List Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation which has the details.  You can also refer to known limitations of Graph [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#permissions-for-groups-and-microsoft-teams).
A user voice on this feature request is also available [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38780761-read-group-calendar-using-application-permission-m) and you can upvote the same so that the product team can include into their plans.

Comment: User Voice does not exist any more. Can you update the link?