# Microsoft GraphAPI subscription for events of a user group not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What works totally fine in my case is to register a web hook subscription on the graph api for a user

```
/user/{id}/events
```

What I do not get to work is a registration for groups:

```
/groups/{id}/events
```

The error message is:

```
Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again
```

How can I find out what is missing concretely? What are the permission that are required  to do a subscription on calendar events on a user group instead of doing it on a user. At the end the idea is to subscribe to all events of all users of the given group. Or is this not possible with the GraphAPI?

Actual question, irrelevant of all the limitations that the graph-api has as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#permissions-for-groups-and-microsoft-teams) which is also mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706603/how-to-access-a-group-calendar-using-microsoft-graph-api):

Would

```
/groups/{id}/events
```

If permission are set correctly be intended to react on changes to the calendars of all users in that group? If not what would be intended way to do this with the graph-api?

I posted this idea with Microsoft: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/be-able-to-subscribe-to-calender/idi-p/3297497

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK currently this functionality is not supported. Being said that, consider filing [UserVoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) for your specific ask so it could be considered for future implementations. I would also recommend posting this to Graph's Issues page so it gets in front of the proper folks from Exchange/Outlook.

Comment: UserVoice does not exist any more.
Where do I find a graphs issue page?